# Missing Maven Repositories node in Services tab in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-12

Maven is installed on my computer and Netbeans can find it because I can create a new project from Archetype just fine. However, I need to add some repositories on Maven but I don't know any other way other than the one in the services tab, but for some reason, the `Maven Repositories` node in the services tab had gone missing (it was there before). I tried restarting netbeans and closing the services tab and opening it again. Is there any other way to add repositories to Maven or have the `Maven Repositories` show up again?

I am using Apache Netbeans 12.

Thanks.

Edit:
I attached a screenshot of the specific problem. I have Maven correctly installed and can create a new project. But I can't add a new archetype catalog because "Maven repositories" is missing:
[image: Missing Maven]

After checking the suggestion of @skomisa, the log showed that the error is caused by me adding a repository that is unavailable. How do I remove this repository since the "Maven Repositories" option is unavailable in services? Thank you.

Comment: [1] Select **Tools > Options > Java**, and then click the **Maven** tab. Does everything look OK? [2] As a workaround, directly edit **settings.xml** yourself, to create additional `<repository>` entries under `repositories`. That file is located within your NetBeans installation directory as **{NB dir}/java/maven/conf/settings.xml**. [3] Check the NetBeans error log (**View > IDE Log**) for any error messages related to your problem that get logged when you start NetBeans. [4] Consider upgrading to NetBeans 12.4 (if you are not running that already). It will contain more bug fixes.

Comment: @skomisa Hi, I did your suggestion and found that a repository that I added earlier was the culprit showing `java.net.UnknownHostException`. Is there any way I can remove this faulty repository so Maven can load properly? Thanks.

Comment: I also checked in the settings.xml but the faulty repository isn't listed there.

Answer (score 0):

1. NetBeans is coming with bundled version of Maven. So when you've installed maven and NetBeans is able to create a new project. It does not mean NetBeans is using our installed version of Maven.
2. When you add a repository to the services tab it already mentions:

> Adding a repository here doesn't affect your Maven builds in any way.
> It's only used to provide the IDE with information from the repositorie's index

3. Since you haven't described what you want with that repository I assume that it's needed to retrieve artifacts from that repo. So most likely you need to add the repo to your project's `pom.xml` in the [`<repositories>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) section.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling Netbeans and deleting the cache in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local and Roaming.